# android Rx-java + Retrofit2 error with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, retrofit2

I am trying to build an android app with MVVM pattern.

Everything is good except rx-java part.

Using Observer in subscribe, I have got an error like this.

```
Error:(28, 18) None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public final fun subscribe(p0: ((Flyer!) -> Unit)!): Subscription! defined in rx.Observable
public final fun subscribe(p0: Observer<in Flyer!>!): Subscription! defined in rx.Observable
public final fun subscribe(p0: Subscriber<in Flyer!>!): Subscription! defined in rx.Observable
public final fun subscribe(p0: Action1<in Flyer!>!): Subscription! defined in rx.Observable
```

My code

```
override fun getflyers(observer: Observer<List<Flyer>>) {
        homeService.flyer(createMap())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(observer) // error here
    }
```

Any ideas for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your observer is `Observer<List<Flyer>>` but you need an `Observer<Flyer>`. The service is emitting Flyers and your observer is looking for lists of them. Probably want to redo your observer as `Observer<Flyer>`

Comment: Oh..man I got it. In retrofit, it was Observer<Flyer> and corrected it to Observer<List<Flyer>>. Thank you Thank you!